# Máscara para Ionic 3

Tags: ionic3

Estou precisando usar máscaras no Ionic 3. Preciso que a máscara funcione no ion-input, já testei o text-mask mas sem sucesso.

Alguma dica de como fazer?

Comment: **Resumidamente** Faça uma diretiva que esteja conectado a este input ao dar InputChange tu modifica ela como quer. Essa tua pergunta foi respondida aqui: [Link para uma pergunta do stack que está em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45198560/ionic-3-input-mask) E se tu quiser ainda pode usar um pacote ainda em funcionamento na versão 3 que é do ionic2: [Package NPM para criar máscaras facilmente](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic2-input-mask)

Answer (score 3):

Veja o que [encontrei](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cpf-cnpj-input-mask/109595) no fórum do `ionic`. Pelos comentários funciona dentro do input.

Coloque esses dados no `html`:

```
 <form #loginForm="ngForm">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>CPF/CNPJ</ion-label>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="cpf_cnpj" (blur)="cpf_cnpj = format(cpf_cnpj)" name="cpf_cnpj"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <button ion-button full type="submit" color="sicor" (tap)="login(signForm.value)">Login</button>
</form>
```

e esses na sua folha `.ts`

```
import { MenuController, NavParams, ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { IonicPage, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {

  cpf_cnpj = '';
  DECIMAL_SEPARATOR=".";
  GROUP_SEPARATOR=",";
  pureResult: any;
  maskedId: any;
  val: any;
  v: any;

constructor(
  public modalCtrl: ModalController, 
  private alertCtrl: AlertController,
  private menu: MenuController,
  public navCtrl: NavController, 
  ){} 

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.menu.swipeEnable(false);
  }
  ionViewWillLeave(){
    this.menu.swipeEnable(true);
  }

  format(valString) {
    if (!valString) {
        return '';
    }
    let val = valString.toString();
    const parts = this.unFormat(val).split(this.DECIMAL_SEPARATOR);
    this.pureResult = parts;
    if(parts[0].length <= 11){
      this.maskedId = this.cpf_mask(parts[0]);
      return this.maskedId;
    }else{
      this.maskedId = this.cnpj(parts[0]);
      return this.maskedId;
    }
};

unFormat(val) {
    if (!val) {
        return '';
    }
    val = val.replace(/\D/g, '');

    if (this.GROUP_SEPARATOR === ',') {
        return val.replace(/,/g, '');
    } else {
        return val.replace(/\./g, '');
    }
};

 cpf_mask(v) {
    v = v.replace(/\D/g, ''); //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
    v = v.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/, '$1.$2'); //Coloca um ponto entre o terceiro e o quarto dígitos
    v = v.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/, '$1.$2'); //Coloca um ponto entre o terceiro e o quarto dígitos
    //de novo (para o segundo bloco de números)
    v = v.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{1,2})$/, '$1-$2'); //Coloca um hífen entre o terceiro e o quarto dígitos
    return v;
}

 cnpj(v) {
    v = v.replace(/\D/g, ''); //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
    v = v.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d)/, '$1.$2'); //Coloca ponto entre o segundo e o terceiro dígitos
    v = v.replace(/^(\d{2})\.(\d{3})(\d)/, '$1.$2.$3'); //Coloca ponto entre o quinto e o sexto dígitos
    v = v.replace(/\.(\d{3})(\d)/, '.$1/$2'); //Coloca uma barra entre o oitavo e o nono dígitos
    v = v.replace(/(\d{4})(\d)/, '$1-$2'); //Coloca um hífen depois do bloco de quatro dígitos
    return v;
}

  public login(formData) { 
       ....you auth code here.
}
```

Aqui uma [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45198560/ionic-3-input-mask) parecida no stackoverflow em inglês que pode vir a ser útil.

Answer (score 1):

tem o https://github.com/amarkes/br-masker-ionic-3

ao instalar e importar você pode utilizar como

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-input type="text" name="cpf" placeholder="CPF" [brmasker]="{mask:'000.000.000-00', len:14}"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aqui vai um exemplo de máscara espero que resolva.
Este aqui formata para apenas números

No .ts:

```
formatarIdade()
    {
       var idade = this.cadastro.idade;

       if(this.cadastro.idade != undefined){
        idade = idade.replace(/\D/g, '');
        this.afogamento.idade = idade;
        console.log(this.cadastro.idade);
       }

    }
```

No .html:

```
<ion-input type="tel" placeholder="Insira a idade" name="idade" maxlength="2" (keyup)="formatarIdade()" pattern="[0-9]" [(ngModel)]="cadastro.idade" required></ion-input>
```